# Paste universal link in iOS 9 safari, but app does not open automatically

Tags: ios, safari, ios-universal-links

If I paste a universal link in safari in iOS 9, it still requires user to manually pull down to see the panel/banner, and then click the “Open App” in order to launch the app. Is this the normal behavior for safari in iOS 9?

But, if I paste links in Facebook(app), Twitter(app), Mail(app) ... all directly open the app. Even if I go to Facebook on Safari and then click on a universal link, the app opens directly.

Only if I paste a universal link directly in to safari search bar, the app does not open directly. It requires the user to click the “Open App” banner.

Is there any way to make Safari auto-launch the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually expected behavior: for better or worse, pasting a Universal Link directly into the Safari URL field doesn't cause the app to open.

[This page](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links) has a list of apps that are known to support Universal Links, and under which conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: My pleasure! If you're looking for a way to automate a lot of these complexities, you could give our free [Branch.io](https://branch.io) deep linking service a look, because we can help handle edge cases like these.